# Word problem: finding third component of vector when two components and the total resultant is given

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, physics

Question appears to be simple, as it did to me. I'm a bit weak in math but that doesn't help me from improving. During my college physics, I encountered this question and found its solution but can't understand it. Can anyone elaborate the highlighted sections in the pics below?

> Three chains act on the bracket such that they create a resultant force having magnitude $F_R$. If two of the chains are subjected to known forces, as shown, determine the orientation $\theta$ of the third chain, measured clockwise from the positive $x$-axis, so that the magnitude of force $F$ in this chain is a minimum. All forces lie in the $x-y$ plane. What is the magnitude of $F$?
>
> **Hint:** First find the resultant of the two known forces. Force F acts in this direction.

[image: force_diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the author decided to measure positive angles in the clockwise direction from the positive $x$-axis, The measure of angle $\phi$ is negative.  Therefore, since $\boldsymbol{F_1}$ points along the negative $y$-axis, the angle between vectors $\boldsymbol{F_1}$ and $\boldsymbol{F_2}$ is $90^\circ - \phi$.

To minimize the force $\boldsymbol{F}$ required on the third chain, it must point in the same direction as the resultant force $\boldsymbol{F_{R_1}}$, which is why the author says to make $\boldsymbol{F}$ parallel to $\boldsymbol{F_{R_1}}$.